# Call to undefined function issue

Tags: php, wp-load.php

I know there are other, maybe better ways to do what I want to achieve, but I have to use this solution.

I have two stylesheets:

- `style.css` - normal stylesheet
- `style-dynamic.php` - dynamic stylesheet linked to the first one

I'm using some PHP code in the second one, like:

```
#body {
    background-color: <?php echo get_option('theme_background'); ?>;
}
```

Now the point is that the `style-dynamic.php` file doesn't *know* WordPress functions, and the code above gives:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function `get_option()` in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\style-dynamic.php** on line **12**

I guess I have to load `wp_load.php` (only?) and that's tricky, because I'm not sure how exactly? I was trying `require_once`, but I'm not sure I'll be able to jump from theme directory right to the WordPress main dir where `wp-load.php` file is?

**Edit**

Of course

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

Outputs another error:

> Use of undefined constant `ABSPATH` - assumed `'ABSPATH'`

Comment: thank you this is my problem when want to create plugin for wordpress i forget to copy my last version we need to have template of plugin for development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christ, once again I was fighting with something for a few days straight and found a solution 20 minutes after asking on StackExchange. WHY?

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully better late than never; in case the solution above (by Wordpressor) is not working, you can load wp-load.php like this:

```
// allow us to use core wordpress functions
    $oldURL = dirname(__FILE__);
    $newURL = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wp-content' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'themes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'THEME_NAME' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'assets', '', $oldURL);
    include($newURL . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wp-load.php');
```

Make sure to replace THEME_NAME with your theme's name.